# Extract MySQL Blob and add to PHP array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, blob

I need to extract a list of keywords from a MySQL database. Each keyword is separated by a comma. I need to read it from the blob, then add it to the array. How would this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First retrieve the blob from the database `SELECT blob FROM tbl WHERE id=123`. The PHP code used to execute the query depends on the SQL API you are using: *mysql, mysqli, PDO, ...*

Once you have a string containing the comma separated data use `explode` to split the words into an array `$array = explode(',', $string)`.

Note that you should probably use the TEXT datatype in this case. Unlike BLOB it is collation and encoding aware. Use BLOB for pure binary data like a JPEG file.